# When will deleted data be permanently gone from Heroku postgres continuous backups?

Tags: backup, heroku, secure-delete

According to [Heroku Postgres Data Safety and Continuous Protection](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-data-safety-and-continuous-protection) data is backed up continuously into Amazon S3 buckets.

If I delete a bunch of rows, for example, all confidential data from 1 particular client, when can I assure the client that the data has been fully and irrevocably erased?

I can't find any information on how long the backups are kept for from Heroku.

Comment: You should probably ask Heroku that

Comment: Yeah. I was hoping that maybe there was a public page that I had missed, guess not.

Comment: @ChristopherJ did you get an answer to this question?